# jQuery: change a table row into a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html-table

What is the best method in jQuery to change a particular table row into a form ?

For example to change :

```
<table>
    <tr><td><a href="edit me">edit</a></td><td>first row</td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="edit me">edit</a></td><td>some row</td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="edit me">edit</a></td><td>last row</td></tr>
</table>
```

into :

```
<table>
    <tr><td><a href="edit me">edit</a></td><td>first row</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <form>
            <td><a href="edit me">edit</a></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='a' value='b'/></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><a href="edit me">edit</a></td><td>last row</td></tr>
</table>
```

Update : the html we finally use :

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img class="editRow"></td>
            <td class="field">field to know</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and the jQuery code :

```
$( ".editRow" ).click( function() {
    var rowToEdit = $(this).parent().parent();
    var field = rowToEdit.children(".field")
    rowToEdit = .replaceWith( "<td></td>\
        <td>\
            <input type='hidden' value='"+field+"'>\
        </td>"
});
```

Comment: You are trying to make the HTML invalid. Don't do that, browsers will error recover in various, different and unwanted ways.

Comment: You need plugin or you are trying to do on your own?

Comment: Sandeep Manne: I can use jquery-1.5.1.min.js, jquery.ui.core ui.widget ui.mouse ui.button ui.draggable ui.position ui.resizable ui.dialog

Comment: Quentin: this html was only an example. My question was more general : What is the best method in jQuery to change a particular table row into a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the function `.wrap()`. For more infomation see [here](http://visualjquery.com/).

Answer (score -2):

There is a jquery function that does exactly what you are revering to, basically it allows you to create a table and then each cell is editable so you don't have to use  just google it a bit. You will find it